# Finding the coefficient of $x^n$ and radius of convergence of $f(x)=\frac{5}{1-3x}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

My question is to:

1) Calculate the coefficient of $x^n$ in the Taylor expansion of $f(x)$

2) Find the radius of convergence of this series

when $f(x)=\frac{5}{1-3x}$

For the first part I recognised that it was of the form $f(x)=\frac{a}{1-r}$ so then $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty ar^n$ which then translated as $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty 5(3x)^n$, so I concluded that the coefficient of $x^n$ was $5(3^n)$.

Secondly for the ratio of convergence, I knew that $|r|\lt 1$ so $|3x|\lt 1$ therefore the ratio of convergence is $\frac{1}{3}$.

This was for an online quiz, however it was only marked as partially correct and did not give any feedback so I am not sure which is right or wrong? If anyone could shed any light on if my answers were correct of not then that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That's weird, because your answer seems correct to me.

Comment: Your answer is totally fine.

Comment: Apparently it is "partially correct"

Comment: Ok thank you guys, maybe a formatting error, the CAS is very picky....

Comment: "ratio of convergence" or "radius of convergence"?  Radius of convergence is always the distance (from origin if that's the point of power series expansion) to nearest singularity (in the complex plane).  So $1/3$ is both the nearest singularity and the radius of convergence.

Comment: Sorry meant radius, changed now sorry for confusion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RE: Solved, contacted course administrator and was CAS error!